# It is possible to luaj convert a script to the binary representation of lua 5.2

Tags: lua, bytecode, bytecode-manipulation, luaj

I am trying to convert a script to binary representation using string.dump, but I saw that the luaj 3.0.1 representation is different from lua 5.2, has some way of changing this, or turns the luaj 3.0.1 representation into lua 5.2 ?

***Code***

```java
Globals _G = JsePlatform.standardGlobals();
LuaValue Function = _G.load("return string.dump(function() return 'Test' end),true);");
String Return = Function.call().toString();
```

***Output in Hex***

```
1B 4C 75 61 52 0 0 4 4 4 8 0 19 93 D A 1A A 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1F 0 80 0 1F 0 0 0 1 4 0 0 0 5 54 65 73 74 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Please upload binary representation generated by luaj

Comment: Done, i upload.

Comment: This is a correct Lua 5.2 bytecode for 32-bit big-endian CPU.  You can use [this tool](https://lua-bytecode.github.io/) to convert a Lua bytecode to another platform (select `L4808` for converting to x64).

Comment: How i select L4808 Sorry, i'm is new in luaj

Comment: `bytecode_x64 = require"lua-bytecode"(string.dump(your_function), "L4808")`, the module is [here](https://github.com/lua-bytecode/lua-bytecode.github.io/blob/master/lua-bytecode.lua)

Comment: Man, I'm sorry, I saw it here and the problem is saving, for some reason when I write a file in java it is nullifying the null bytes, I'm sorry for bothering you so much  

Comment: The problem "How Java could save a binary file containing zero bytes" deserves separate SO question.  It is not luaj-specific.