# Changing the size of lua numbers in compiled lua script

Tags: lua, bytecode, bytecode-manipulation, luac, luadec

My goal is to decompile, modify and recompile a lua script. I can do this easily expect that the header of the resulting binary file changes from the original one.
The binary chunk I decompile starts with the following header:

> 1b4c 7561 5100 0104 0804 0400

The header in the generated file is:

> 1b4c 7561 5100 0104 0804 0800

As you can see the only thing that changes between them is the value of `Size of lua_Number` ([source](http://luaforge.net/docman/83/98/ANoFrillsIntroToLua51VMInstructions.pdf), see page 7)

I've tried changing the target platform and even the version but couldn't get the correct header in the end. Is there by any chance a way to set this as an option in some way?

Comment: You can use [this tool](https://lua-bytecode.github.io/) to convert a Lua bytecode to another platform and/or another size of numbers. Select your generated bytecode and convert it to EnBi `L4804`.

Comment: Another option would be to build Lua with `#define LUA_NUMBER float` instead of `#define LUA_NUMBER double` (see details in luaconf.h) - this Lua will generate bytecode having 4-byte float numbers.

Comment: Thanks you two for you suggestions. I didn't try the tool yet, mostly because it'd be a bit problematic to do this manually each time. Modifying lua's sources works well and allows me to recompile scripts exactly as they were originally. This is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: You can run this tool programmatically, see comments under [the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58428342/it-is-possible-to-luaj-convert-a-script-to-the-binary-representation-of-lua-5-2)